# Множественное число слов ПРАКТИКА и ТЕХНИКА

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

Всегда считал, что правильно не «много разных техник (мн. ч.) ведения опросов», а «много разной техники (ед. ч.) ведения опросов».
Или не так: много разных тренировочных практик, а много разной тренировочной практики.
Не духовные практики, а духовная практика. На крайний случай — разные виды духовной практики.

Имеют ли слова ПРАКТИКА и ТЕХНИКА (не аппараты, а совокупность приемов) множественное число?

Comment: ТЕХНИКА - это существительное, в любом значении. Возможно,  Вы имели ввиду "практика и техника" - как мастерство?

Comment: Не "наречие", а "отвлеченное существительное". Нет?!

Answer (score 1):

Имеют - кака минимум в разговорной и профессиональной речи.
Причем именно в таком значении: как совокупность учений и приемов для достижения какой-либо цели, оформленная в некую систему, школу.

Словари, правда, такое значение выносят за скобки, но вот есть нечто близкое.

Практика

> 5. Накопленный опыт, совокупность приёмов и навыков в какой-л. области 
>      деятельности.

Техника

> 4. Совокупность профессиональных приёмов, используемых в каком-л. деле, 
>      мастерстве, искусстве

Даже в этих значениях множественное число представляется вполне возможным.

Духовные практики - устоявшийся термин. А как и, например, "техники письма" в живописи. 
Вообще замечено, что в профессиональной речи, там где часто необходимо противопоставление объектов, не имеющих обычно формы множественного числа, такие формы появляются. В технике, например, это "бензины" или "бетоны". С "техниками" и "практиками" - нечто подобное.